# Why avoid the word "please" in error messages?

Tags: error-message, emotion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should an interface ever say “please”?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10853/should-an-interface-ever-say-please)

According to [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines (UX Guide) for Windows 7 and Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511267.aspx#text):

> **Avoid the word "please,"** except in situations in which the user is asked to do something inconvenient (such as waiting) or the software is to blame for the situation. 
>   **Correct:**
>   Please wait while Windows copies the files to your computer.

I always use *"please"* in my error message for it to be polite, like

> ... *please* enter a value in the username field.

Why do we need to avoid the word "please" for errors like this? Won't adding "please" make the message more polite?

Comment: @AndroidHustle Close, but this question is more specific - and should stay open imho

Comment: @BennySkogberg ok, that's a fair observation, I don't agree though. If you read the question and the approved answer from Jimmy Breck-McKye, that situation is very much transferable to this situation. Meaning that error messages should aid users in completing the task rather than "excusing itself" by saying "Please". Imho the reasoning behind the two questions is totally transferable, but maybe were just seeing it differently. =)

Comment: @AndroidHustle Förmodligen är det en sån där Stockholm vs. Skåne-grej igen :-)

Comment: @BennySkogberg haha! det har du kanske rätt i! =)

Comment: @AndroidHustle - +1 just for spelling my name correctly. Everyone gets it wrong.

Comment: @JimmyBreck-McKye it's surprisingly easy getting it right using Ctrl+C! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only Microsoft uses the guidance on avoiding *please* in Error Messages. [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/specs/collaterals/guides/_components.inv/UITextStyleGuide.html), a Microsoft Office competitor, also lets the developer know to avoid please:

> Use “please” only rarely, if ever. Sometimes lengthy instructions or error messages might need a touch of politeness added to one of several sentences, but generally, do not use “please” in English. If you still feel the need, at least avoid using “please” more than once in one text or group of sentences. For example, you could use “please” in the initial instructions on the first page of a wizard, but then not on any of the other pages. **Simple imperative sentences are always preferred**.

However, there are cultural differences. In German the word "bitte" is almost always used in Error Messages, so be careful to use Google Translate or other automated translating services in a Multi-lingual application.

Comment: Interesting - do you think this might be MS's way of being a grammar nazi? Are they doing this for "The greater good" so that we all learn to use please properly or are they genuinely doing it with UX in mind?

Comment: @TJH From your reply I can see you're not the biggest fan of Microsoft, but they have spent and are spending a lot on User Experiece research and test. I would think they have UX close to heart on all they do. Their horrible browser Internet Explorer does technical errors up to version 9, but from a UX perspective it's the only browser having a bigger back-button and thus implementing Fitts's Law on the webs most used control.

Comment: @TJH wow... "grammar nazi"...? why would MS care how people use the word "Please" in their every day life?

Comment: I'm not anti-MS at all, don't have emotional attachments to OS's like many do. I don't know WHY MS would care I'm merely wondering whether they're doing it for the sake of THAT UI that you're wording, or if they're doing it to try and solve the bigger problem of the word 'Please' becoming a cliché - all within the scope of "on a computer" - I'm not suggesting MS should be the custodian of the English Language's usage.

Comment: @TJH Oh, I misunderstood you then. I think they only want to help developers making better applications for Users, and not trying to be Language Police Force.

Comment: @Benny Skogeberg I can't agree with your statement in German the word "please" will used in every error message. Many applications e.g. MS, Adobe don't use please.

Comment: @TJH An important thing to remember is that the quality of third party applications developed for Windows will ultimately reflect on how the overall opinion is formed in the end user regarding the platform. In other words, MS benefits from third party developers making good quality software for their platform. It seams obvious but that's all there is to it

Comment: @sysscore Does your Adobe software produce a lot of error messages?

Comment: @Benny Skogeberg Not really... That's the best concept. :-)

Answer (score 5):

**Overused words lose their meaning**. It is called [Cliche](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clich%C3%A9).

If you use *please*, and *thank you* for every user action then the effect flattens and you don't have its full strength when you need it to sound meaningly.

> Avoid the word "please," **except in situations in which the user is asked to do something inconvenient** [...]