# Do you use the word "please" on your website?

Tags: copywriting, content

We are developing a new product/website and one of our product managers said we should never use the word "please" either on our website or in our transactional emails.

Personally, I disagree. We are trying to make our site casual and friendly and I think using the word "please" is just polite.

What do you think?

Comment: Here's a previous thread discussing this same topic.  http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10853/should-an-interface-ever-say-please    It's easy to overuse or misuse the word "please".  It can also come across as cold and stern, rather than friendly and polite.  There are ways to write content in warm tone without using 'please'.  On the other hand, I also disagree with the manager that on setting such blanket rule.